# Pandas sort by two column values

Tags: pandas

With this dataframe:

```
item  XP_home       XP_away 
A     0.000000      5.229861  
B     6.412500      0.000000  
C     5.037361      0.000000  
D     0.000000      3.394792
```

I can sort like so:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='XP_home', ascending=False).head(2)
```

and get:

```
B     6.412500      0.000000  
C     5.037361      0.000000
```

or:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='XP_away', ascending=False).head(2)
```

and get:

```
A     0.000000      5.229861  
D     0.000000      3.394792
```

But how can I sort by the highest of *both* column values, to get:

```
item  XP_home       XP_away 
B     6.412500      0.000000
A     0.000000      5.229861    
C     5.037361      0.000000  
D     0.000000      3.394792
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us try `argsort`

```
out = df.iloc[(-df.filter(like = 'XP').max(1)).argsort()]
  item   XP_home   XP_away
1    B  6.412500  0.000000
0    A  0.000000  5.229861
2    C  5.037361  0.000000
3    D  0.000000  3.394792
```

Comment: Definitely the way to go

Answer (score 2):

You can sort on the max value across rows:

```
print (df.assign(val=df[["XP_home", "XP_away"]].max(1))
         .sort_values("val", ascending=False).drop("val", 1))

  item   XP_home   XP_away
1    B  6.412500  0.000000
0    A  0.000000  5.229861
2    C  5.037361  0.000000
3    D  0.000000  3.394792
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `pandas 1.1.0` you can compute the sorting values with the [`key`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) argument

```
df.sort_values('XP_home', key=lambda _: df[['XP_away', 'XP_home']].max(1), ascending=False)
```

Out:

```
  item   XP_home   XP_away
1    B  6.412500  0.000000
0    A  0.000000  5.229861
2    C  5.037361  0.000000
3    D  0.000000  3.394792
```